# Настройка виртуального сетевого интерфейса QEMU/KVM, ошибка выдачи ip

Tags: centos, kvm, qemu

Коллеги, подскажите где допустил ошибку с мостом в QEMU/KVM? Система centos 9. Мост создан и при выборе в UI(QEMU/KVM, в окошке с выбором Виртуального сетевого интерфейса) система сама выдавала ip виртуалке, щас же перестала. Ubuntu которая крутиться виртуально пишет «Сбой подключения».
[image: окно выбора устройства]

```
root@localhost /]# ip a
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp42s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bridge0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:7c:16:b5:32:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: bridge0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:7c:16:b5:32:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.126/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute bridge0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5e09:d90c:1c80:e68/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:bb:53:bb:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:00:99:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master virbr0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:18:0a:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[root@localhost /]# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev bridge0 proto static metric 425 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev bridge0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.126 metric 425 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 
[root@localhost /]# cat /etc/sysctl.conf |grep ipv4
[root@localhost /]# virsh iface-list
 Имя       Состояние   MAC-адрес
------------------------------------------
 bridge0   активен     04:7c:16:b5:32:8a
 virbr0    активен     52:54:00:00:99:28
```

Answer (score 0):

На основании предоставленной информации, ваш мост (bridge0) находится в активном состоянии, и у него есть IP-адрес (192.168.0.126/24), что должно позволить виртуальным машинам получать IP-адреса через DHCP, если этот функционал настроен.

Однако, возможные причины сбоя подключения в виртуальной машине Ubuntu могут быть следующими:

Неправильные настройки сети внутри виртуальной машины: Убедитесь, что виртуальная машина настроена на использование DHCP для получения IP-адреса или убедитесь, что вы задали статический IP-адрес в том же подсетевом диапазоне, что и мост (bridge0).

Firewall или другие настройки безопасности: Проверьте настройки брандмауэра на хосте и внутри виртуальной машины Ubuntu. Возможно, что брандмауэр блокирует сетевой трафик.

Проблемы с DHCP-сервером: Если вы используете DHCP для выдачи IP-адресов в сети, убедитесь, что DHCP-сервер работает корректно и доступен из виртуальной машины Ubuntu.

Проблемы с маршрутизацией или DNS: Проверьте маршруты внутри виртуальной машины Ubuntu (ip route) и DNS-настройки (/etc/resolv.conf).

Проблемы с сетевыми интерфейсами внутри виртуальной машины: Убедитесь, что сетевые интерфейсы внутри виртуальной машины Ubuntu настроены корректно и активны.

Проверьте эти аспекты и выполните необходимые настройки для устранения сбоя подключения в виртуальной машине Ubuntu.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Виртуальная машина тут не играет роли, при создании новой виртуалки проблемы сохраняются, они не получают ip. DHCP работает нормально, при переключении на NAT, все начинает работать